# C# working with strings and Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have such a string

```
|   7   |      2       |39,93 |
```

and I need to split it into an array where the first element is `"7"`, second `"2"` and third is `"39,93"`

I've came up with the following solution

```
var line     =  "|   7   |      2       |39,93 |";
line = line.Remove(0, 1);
string[] arr = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", "").Trim().Split('|');
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Can it be `List<double>`?

Comment: take a look at string.split(), then use trim() for the spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need regex for this, you can do it using `String.Split` and some LINQ like:

```
var line = "|   7   |      2       |39,93 |";
var array = line.Split(new[] { '|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Comment: @xanatos, why ? The OP needs, 3 elements in the array

Comment: Hadn't seen the RemoveEmptyEntries... That could generate problems if there are empty columns...

Comment: by the time visual studio loaded + started a new console application + verified my soltuion works, you already posted it. +1 for you, -1 for visual studio 2017.

Comment: Or if whitespace is the only extraneous char just `line.Replace(" ", "").Split(...`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
var output =
    line.Split("|") // split on the pipes
        .Select(x => x.Trim()) // remove excess whitespace from each item
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) // remove any empty items
        .ToArray(); // convert to array
```

Regexes don't really help you very much here. You *could* do it with a regex, but it'd probably be harder to read. There's a possibility it might be more efficient though. You'd have to test that.

I'm anticipating empty items appearing at the start and end that need to be dropped because of those initial and terminal pipes, but if there are empty elements in the middle that you wanted to keep you'd have to adjust that part.